# Fujitsu HPC Gateway Addon - How To Use Separate Files

Tags: extjs, hpc

How can I split the logic for an HPC Gateway Addon into separate files? i.e. I'd like to do something like this:

**Main.js**

```js
Ext.define('App.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    items: [{
        title: 'Stuff',
        xtype: 'stuff',
        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-object-group'
    }, {
        title: 'About',
        xtype: 'about',
        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-info-circle',
    }]
});
```

**Stuff.js**

```js
Ext.define('App.widget.Stuff', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.stuff',
    html: '<h1>Stuff'
});
```

**About.js**

```js
Ext.define('App.widget.About', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.about',
    html: '<h1>Version: x.y.z'
});
```

According to the official fujitsu docs for [creating an addon](https://docs.fujitsu.fr/HPCGateway/current/doku.php?id=fujitsu:hpcgateway:guides:developpers:addon&s[]=addon#add_content_into_addon), there are no examples of separating your logic into multiple files, just two monolithic files which contain the view & the controller logic:

**appModule.js**

```js
Ext.define('desktop.addons.app_abcdef12.view.appModule', {
    extend: 'desktop.core.utils.Module',
    requires:[],

    /**
     * Create window
     * @param taskBar the task bar
     * @returns {desktop.core.view.utils.ModuleView} the module view
     */
    createWindow: function (taskBar) {
        var me = this;
        return Ext.create('desktop.core.view.utils.ModuleView', {
            title: me.title,
            iconCls: me.iconCls,
            stateId: 'app-module',
            name: 'app-window',
            taskBar: taskBar,
            multipleView: false,
            width: 320,
            height: 150,
            items:me.buildItems(),
            buttons: [
            ]
        });
    },

    /**
     * Build items
     * @returns {{xtype: string, layout: {type: string, align: string}, items: *[]}} items in json format
     */
    buildItems:function(){
        return {
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: 'center',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'value',
                fieldLabel: desktop.core.utils.Symbols.getText('app_abcdef12.textfield.input')+" *",
                allowBlank:false,
                listeners: {
                    change: function(textfield, newValue){
                        var window = textfield.up('window');
                        window.fireEvent('textfieldChanged', textfield, newValue);
                    }
                }
            }]
        };
    }
});
```

**appController.js**

```js
Ext.define('desktop.addons.app_abcdef12.controller.appController', {
    extend: 'desktop.core.controller.abstract.AbstractToriiController',
    requires: [],
    control: {
        'window[name=app-window]': {
            textfieldChanged: 'performTextfieldChanged'
        }
    },

    performTextfieldChanged: function (textfield, newValue) {
        if (Ext.isEmpty(newValue)) {
            textfield.up('window').down('button[name=save]').disable();
        } else {
            textfield.up('window').down('button[name=save]').enable();
        }
    }
});
```

When I tried to create something like `desktop.addons.app_abcdef12.view.Stuff` with an xtype of `widget.stuff` I crashed the HPC instance, and had to delete the addon listed in mongodb and restart the services. This seriously reduces the number of times I can use trial and error to find out what works.

Anybody done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I didn't manage to get anything working using `xtype` but I did when using [`Ext.create`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.html#method-create) directly:

**appModule.js**

```
buildItems:function(){
    return {
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        items: [
            Ext.create('desktop.addons.app_abcdef12.view.Stuff'),
            Ext.create('desktop.addons.app_abcdef12.view.About'),
        ]
    };
}
```

**Stuff.js**

```
Ext.define('desktop.addons.app_abcdef12.view.Stuff', {
    title: 'Stuff',
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-id-card',
    html: '<h1>Stuff'
});
```

**About.js**

```
Ext.define('desktop.addons.app_abcdef12.view.About', {
    title: 'About',
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-info',
    html: '<h1>About'
});
```